# Three fair coins are tossed. What is the probability that

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Three fair coins are tossed. What is the probability that they are all heads if the first coin is head?

I am stuck after writing down $P(3H|FirstHead)=\frac{P(FirstHead|3H)P(3H)}{P(FirstHead)}$

P(FirstHead) = ? $({3\choose1} (1/2)(1/2)^2)$

P(3H) = ? $(1/2)^3$

So confusing, can't get any further. How can we approach it ?

Comment: This is the same as requiring that the last two coins come up $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all independent events.

So, the first coin being a head has no effect on the other two coins being heads. That being said, the probability of all three being heads given the first is a head, is simply the probability that the last two are heads.

This happens with probability $\displaystyle \frac{1}{4}$.